# Error when istaling healpy with pip. I have Python 3.9.7

Tags: healpy

I cannot install healpy using pip and Python 3.9 - Windows 10.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for healpy
Failed to build healpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for healpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: healpy doesn't support Windows

Comment: Yes, I saw this later. Thanks for your answer.